# When using "bundle" packaging with maven-bundle-plugin goals are executed twice

Tags: java, maven, maven-bundle-plugin

I have a (simple) maven project with packaging type "bundle" using `org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.4`. It produces a correct OSGI bundle jar. However i observe that all goals are executed at least *twice*. How do i prevent this? Problem is that some goals (checkstyle in this example) are slow so duplicate execution is a problem here.

**NOTE**: I use maven 3.2.5 from the command line.

Output or `mvn clean install` (removed all irrelevant info). Notice that many plugins are executed 4 times. `maven-checkstyle-plugin` is execurted twice.

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ my-project ---
[INFO] >>> maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.4:bundle (default-bundle) > package @ my-project >>>
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ my-project ---
[INFO] <<< maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.4:bundle (default-bundle) < package @ my-project <<<
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.4:bundle (default-bundle) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:check (checkstyle-main) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ my-project ---
[INFO] >>> maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.4:install (default-install) > install @ my-project >>>
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ my-project ---
[INFO] >>> maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.4:bundle (default-bundle) > package @ my-project >>>
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ my-project ---
[INFO] <<< maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.4:bundle (default-bundle) < package @ my-project <<<
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.4:bundle (default-bundle) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:check (checkstyle-main) @ my-project ---
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ my-project ---
[INFO] <<< maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.4:install (default-install) < install @ my-project <<<
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.4:install (default-install) @ my-project ---
```

Extra info:

Parent POM

```
<project ...>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>9</version>
    </parent>
    ...
    <version>3.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    ...
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.4</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

POM for OSGI bundle:

```
<project ...>
    <parent>
        <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    </parent>
    ...
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>myPackage</Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**UPDATE**: This is a known bug (also see answer K Erlandsson): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-4882

This issue is resolved now (`maven-bundle-plugin-2.5.5`)

Comment: It will be helpful if you could post that fragment of your pom.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: As *rmuller* have updated in the question, it is a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-4882. The bug is fixed in version `3.0.0`.

---

I recall us having a similar problem (specifically, the bundle was deployed twice) when we upgraded `maven-bundle-plugin` to `2.5.4`. We downgraded it to `2.5.3` to solve our problems.

I have not dug deeper to see if this is a bug or if there are just other requirements for configuration for `2.5.4`.

Comment: Unbelievable! This is it! Downgraded to 2.5.3 and everything works as expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: Downgrading from 2.5.4 to 2.5.3 eliminated the double compile, double javadoc for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to skip goal deploy of `maven-bundle-plugin 2.5.4` with this workaround:

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>default-deploy</id>
    <phase>no-execute</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>deploy</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

This only worked for release numbers with qualifier in my case: e.g. `0.3.0-RC1`.
Release builds with release number without qualifier still did not work: e. g. `0.3.0`.

Downgrading maven-bundle-plugin to 2.5.3 solved this issue, that the bundle was deployed twice. But I faced another issue:
`Maven Bundle Plugin fails with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, "Invalid Class File"`...

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-4556, switching to `bndlib` version `2.4.0` works for me.

So I solved my issues by using `maven-bundle-plugin 2.5.3` and using `bndlib` version `2.4.0`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.3</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
      <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<plugin>
```

Comment: Notice that the issues is resolved as of now (`maven-bundle-plugin-2.5.5`)

Answer (score -1):

The version `maven-bundle-plugin-2.5.5` works for me.