# Why is OSGI bundle module getting built twice

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I am building this multi-module project with Maven. The folder structure of the project at root is as follows:

```
core (dir)
  |--- pom.xml
  |--- pom (dir)
        |---com.loc.dist.core.msp.osgi.pom (dir)
                 |---pom.xml
  |--- com.lgc.dist.core.msp.example.helloservice.client (dir)
                  |---pom.xml
```

Project `com.lgc.dist.core.msp.example.helloservice.client` is packaged as OSGI `bundle` and it is a child module of `com.loc.dist.core.msp.osgi.pom`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.lgc.dist</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.lgc.dist.core.msp.osgi.pom</artifactId>
        <relativePath>../pom/com.lgc.dist.core.msp.osgi.pom</relativePath>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>com.lgc.dist.core.msp.example.helloservice.client</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lgc.dist</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.lgc.dist.core.msp.service</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>com.lgc.dist.core.msp.example.helloservice.client.*;version=${project.version}</Export-Package>
                        <Private-Package>com.lgc.dist.core.msp.example.helloservice.client.internal</Private-Package>
                        <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The `pom.xml` in top level shows `pom` folder and `com.lgc.dist.core.msp.example.helloservice.client` are in the reactor list.

```
<modules>
        <module>pom</module>
        <module>com.lgc.dist.core.msp.example.helloservice.client</module>
    </modules>
```

When I ran `mvn clean install` from the root, it tends to build `com.lgc.dist.core.msp.example.helloservice.client` back to back twice. It is ok to install twice, but it will cause trouble when I run `mvn deploy`. All other submodules just built once. It is only the child modules of `com.loc.dist.core.msp.osgi.pom` are being built twice. I guess osgi builds all the bundle modules by default. But if I comment it out in pom.xml, the osgi bundle modules won't get built at all. What should I do to build these OSGI bundles just once?

**EDIT**  It works fine if I change the packaging mode from `bundle` to `jar`, but that negates the purpose of having OSGI bundles.

Comment: just a guess, did you looked at your "effective pom" ?

Comment: @elizeire what is there to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it turns out `maven-bundle-plugin` 2.5.4 deploys the bundles by default. According to one of the answers of [When using “bundle” packaging with maven-bundle-plugin goals are executed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231453/when-using-bundle-packaging-with-maven-bundle-plugin-goals-are-executed-twice)
 (I'm surprised it did not get any up votes), you need to stop deploying by adding the execution block

```
                 <executions>
                   <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>no-execute</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
```

It is working now.

**EDIT**, based on the comment of this answer, it is resolved in 2.5.5. Haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 1):

Since the project "*com.lgc.dist.core.msp.example.helloservice.client*" is not a direct child of top level pom.xml, remove it from there.

So, in top level pom.xml, the entries should be :

```
<modules>
    <module>pom/com.loc.dist.core.msp.osgi.pom</module>
</modules>
```

And pom.xml in pom/com.loc.dist.core.msp.osgi.pom should be having :

```
<modules>
    <module>com.lgc.dist.core.msp.example.helloservice.client</module>
</modules>
```